# selenium webdriver not open Firefox in jenkins

Tags: firefox, selenium, jenkins, webdriver

> jenkins version: 1.598
>   selenium version: 1.42.2
>   firefox version: 2.7
>   Platform: windows2008 and windows2003

**webtest.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver

class Webtest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    ...
```

I used command "`python webtest.py`" in windows cmd, that's OK

```
d:\python webtest.py
.
--------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 42.978s

OK
```

but, if in jenkins, selected "execute windows batch command" and configure "python webtest.py", has problem, firefox not open, but have process,
At the same time，webtest also be a variety of problems，example:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.42.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 370, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.42.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.42.1-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: u'Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up' ;
```

but，webtest.py in windows cmd executed is successed.

so，i dont't know why? How to make the browser open? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your jenkins is hosted in a Windows machine, there are some special configurations you should know about services that are allow to use the interface.

By the way, the easiest way to see the browsers running is starting jenkins using the command line:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

The main reason for not launching the browser is JNLP (java network launch protocol) , when we execute the war we can interact with the desktop applications.